# Developing a add-on/extension to view PDFs

Tags: firefox-addon, browser-extension

My very specific need is to develop an add-on (aka "extension", I think) for Firefox to view PDF files instead of the built-in PDF viewer.

First, I've spent a bit of time on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions and https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples, but I don't see how to make an add-on that would be an option in Preferences / Applications under 
*"Choose how Firefox handles the files you download from the web or the applications you use while browsing"*.

Is it not possible to build an add-on in this way? Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

In Chrome, it looks like this option is **file_browser_handlers** in the manifest.json.

Answer (score 0):

Answer courtesy of Martin Giger:

I can see at least two ways (with them being achievable in multiple variations as far as I’m aware):

1. Redirect PDFs to an URL within your extension that then handles loading and displaying the PDF. Breaks “Save page as” for saving the PDF
2. Replace the content of the PDF response with your PDF viewer. Means it gets displayed for the URL the PDF is at, but also breaks “Save page as”.